# Grab input value with jquery

Tags: jquery, input

How to get the value of a form input that doesn't have a name or id with jquery.

```
<form id="contact" name="contact" action="/SubmitForm/" method="post">
    <div class="form_input"><input type="text"></div>
    <div class="form_input"><input type="text"></div>
```

..

I think I am selecting the first and second input like so

```
$('#contact input')[0]; 
$('#contact input')[1];
```

but how do i get the value?

Answer (score 0):

This will do:

```
$("input").each(function(){
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `:eq` selector and `.val()` function.

```
var first_val = $('#contact input:eq(0)').val();
var second_val = $('#contact input:eq(1)').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your existing selectors should work fine, provided you add `.value` on the end.

Ex: `$('#contact input')[0].value;`

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/P5Crd/)**

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a loop to go through the elements:

```
$('input').each(function(el) {
  console.log( $(el).val() );
});
```